# Identifying an escaped character

Tags: git, bash, zsh

I have a handy little alias for deleting any Git branches that have been merged into the current branch:

```
alias git_delete_merged_branches='git branch --merged | grep -v "\*" | xargs -n 1 git branch -d'
```

This has been working fine until I updated to the most recent version of Git (2.9), where it suddenly quit working with this error:

```
error: branch 'blah' not found.
```

If I run `git branch --merged | grep -v "\*"`, I get the following output:

```
  blah
```

That seems to be correct, and if I run `echo "  blah\n" | xargs -n 1 git branch -d` everything works fine. I suspected there might be a hidden character getting added by Git, so I ran `git branch --merged | grep -v "\*" | cat -v` and this is the result:

```
  blah^[[m
```

What is the `^[[m` character and how can I get rid of it?

Comment: probably an ansi/vt terminal escape sequence.

Comment: @MarcB Indeed it's an escape sequence. But why is it causing this trouble?

Comment: That's probably an attempt to output some color.  While I do think it's a regression, try `git branch --no-color`

Comment: One more idea: please try this in plain dumb shell (preferably in `/bin/dash` if you have one): to rule out a possibility of some odd interaction of your `zsh` with `git` -- like, say, some `zsh` aliases updated along with Git.

Comment: Aside: `bash` and `zsh` are quite entirely different shells, with major incompatibilities (and differences in best practices) between them and different people having expertise in each. Please consider avoiding conflating them in questions.

Comment: @kostix, re: shell-induced issues, that would be easily checked for by using `set -x` to trace the invocation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the content of your .gitconfig file.

You should have something like

```
[color]
    ui = auto
```

and it should disable colors when output to a pipe.

Comment: That was the answer. Using the `--no-color` flag as @kostix mentioned did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, one should call `git config --get color.ui` to figure out -- because most settings can come out of any of the three configuration sources.

Comment: @LandonSchropp, so, you had `color.ui` set to `true` rather than `auto`, have you?

Comment: @kostix Ah, you're right, it's `always` instead of `auto`.

Answer (score 1):

Its is something on your local machine -
I have tried it both on windows and Unix and it works fine for me.

[image]

Comment: Yep, you were right. It was `ui = always`, as Diego mentioned.